# Attributes to indicate that generic types can be null in some cases

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I'm writing a generic class with an unconstrained generic parameter. So far I have worked out that

- `[AllowNull]` indicates that an input parameter is potentially null
- `[MaybeNull]` indicates that an output parameter is potentially null
- `[return: MaybeNull]` indicates that the return value of a method is potentially null (it has no effect on a property getter!)
- `[MaybeNull]` on a property indicates that the getter can return null (it does not affect the setter)
- `[AllowNull]` on a property indicates that the setter accepts null (it does not affect the getter)

I still have a couple of questions. Given a class like this:

```cs
#nullable enable

class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    Dictionary<int, T> _dict = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    ...

    [MaybeNull]
    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => this[index, default(T)];
        set => _dict[index] = value;
    }

    // [MaybeNull, NotNullIfNotNull("defaultValue")] doesn't work properly
    public T this[int index, [AllowNull] T defaultValue]
    {
        get {
            if (_dict.TryGetValue(index, out T value))
                return value;
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    // [returns IEnumerator<T> if T is struct, IEnumerator<T?> if T is class]
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { ... }
    ...
}

void example()
{
    MyCollection<string> a = new MyCollection<string>();
    string x = a[45];        // Should warn (and it does)
    a[45] = null;            // Should warn (and it does)
    string s1 = a[45, "-"];  // Should not warn
    string s2 = a[45, null]; // Should warn (currently doesn't)
    IEnumerator<string> e1 = a.GetEnumerator(); // Should warn (currently doesn't)
    IEnumerator<string?> e2 = a.GetEnumerator(); // Should not warn
}
```

1. How can I specify that `this[int, T]` can only return null when `defaultValue` is null or when the type parameter is `T?` (e.g. `T = string?`)?
2. How can I specify that `GetEnumerator()` returns `IEnumerator<T>` if `T` is a struct, but `IEnumerator<T?>` if `T` is class?
3. If there were a method that accepted a `Something<T>` parameter, how could I indicate that this means `Something<T>` when `T` is a struct and `Something<T?>` when T is a class?

See also: Microsoft page about [nullability attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)